# Disable body scrolling and leave inner div scrollable in mobile

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile

How can you disable scrolling of the body of a webpage without also disabling the scrolling 
of sections of scrollable content within the window on a mobile device?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to disable the scrolling of the body, you can add in Css

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

then nothing will scroll on your body, but your sections in your body with scrolling content will still be able to scroll.

Comment: That would work but scrollable divs don't have inertia scrolling; they will scroll slow so I'd recommend against it.